# How i can use filter function in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, map-function, filterfunction

I want to delete unwanted characters in dictionary like:$&@“”’’!?,#%*=…
I just want number ,alphabet and underline.

Comment: Hi Yasin, welcome to the site. Wanna show us what you tried? This isn't a free code writing service

Comment: For keys or values? It would be helpful if you provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) that returns `True` if the text isn't in punctuation symbols (that you don't want), except for `'_'` that we will remove with `.replace("_","")`, and then using the `filter` function to apply that to a `list`, then to `join` with `''`:

```
from string import punctuation
string_to_parse = "a$ ehl! th!s i$ "
parse=lambda letter:letter not in punctuation.replace("_",'') 
stringcompleted = ''.join(filter(parse,string_to_parse))
print(stringcompleted)
```

output:

```
'a ehl ths i '
```

You could wrap this into a function, like this:

```
>>> def parses(string_to_parse):
...     parse=lambda letter:letter not in __import__("string").punctuation.replace("_",'')
...     return ''.join(filter(parse,string_to_parse))
...
>>> parses("s/)+(=i;~q8cze%]*'y:|,f")
'siq8czeyf'
```

but this uses dynamic importing, witch from my [test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FttTW.png), results in double the time of the other so i suggest normal importing:

```
>>> def parses(string_to_parse):
...    from string import punctuation
...    parse=lambda letter:letter not in punctuation.replace("_",'')
...    return ''.join(filter(parse,string_to_parse))
>>> parses("s/)+(=i;~q8cze%]*'y:|,f")
'siq8czeyf'
```

Comment: you don't actually need the `list` part: `stringcompleted = ''.join(filter(ffunc,string_to_parse))` works just fine.


Also, the ffunc function can be simplified to `return letter not in punctionation.replace("_", '')`

Comment: oh thanks, i will fix that rn

Comment: why make it an dynamic import and replace every time that the predicate function is called instead of doing those first and only once?

Comment: thanks, that almost got me. I'll change that in a second.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sanitize a string so that it has all special characters removed, try this function:

```
def sanitize(string):
  outstr = ""
  for char in string:
    if char.isalpha() or char.isdigit() or char == "_":
      outstr += char
  return outstr
```